# docker-compose: how to keep showing logs in 'follow' mode even when container is down?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

If you run `docker-compose logs -f service` in one terminal and try to restart `service` in other, then logging will be stopped and you will need to start `dkc logs` again. How to keep `dkc logs` running?

The only solution I've found so far is to run additional noop service which will not allow `dkc logs` to shut down. If this is the only solution then do you have any suggestion for simplest `noop` service which already exists on docker hub?

#### My workaround:

1. add new `noop` service to the `docker-compose.override.yml` (I picked redis because it was already installed and is quite lightweight):

```
services: 
  noop: 
    image: redis:5-alpine
```

2. run `docker-compose logs -f service noop` instead of with just `service`.
3. run `docker-compose stop/restart service`. `logs` process will be kept alive by `noop` service.

Con:

- extra stuff to run
- cannot use `dkc stop` and `dkc restart` without specifying the service

Comment: Your workaround interests me. Can you give more details ? For the moment, I loop on the dkc logs :  `while true; do docker-compose logs -f service;done`. It does the job while it runs a new `logs` subcommand at each termination.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe some information about what you are logging. For example on nginx or php containers we simply move logfiles outside of container just using volume to mount them to host machine, then you can parse them as you want.

```yaml
    volumes:
      - /var/log/mysql/error_service_xy.log:/var/log/mysql/error.log
```